# Does the ID class vector change in Kernel Linear Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: matlab, dimensionality-reduction, kernel-trick, discriminant-analysis, rbf-kernel

Assume that I have a matrix $X$ that has the size $m * n$ and a class ID vector with the length $n$.

If I want to apply Kernel Linear Discriminant Analysis (KLDA) onto the matrix $X$ and vector $y$, then I need to use a kernel onto K. For example a linear kernel.

$$K = X*X^T$$

This will turn $K$ into a $m * m$ matris. But I cannot apply Linear Disciriminant Analysis on $K$ because the ID vector $y$ has not been changed because it's still $n$ in length.

**Question:**

Assume that you have a fully working LDA function

```
% X[m*n]
% y[1*n]
% c integer
% W[m*c]
% P[c*n]
[P, W] = lda(X, y, c)
```

Where $X$ is your data matrix, $y$ is the class ID and $c$ is amount of how many eigenvectors you want to have. $P$ is the projected matrix of $X$ and $W$ contains eigenvectors.

If you want to apply a kernel onto $X$, how should $y$ be chaned then?